# Async Task running very slow

Tags: image, listview, android-asynctask

I am using the async code to fetch images from web inside a for loop. Pls suggest what can I do to generate this list quickly. I pass this data to listview.

```
private class CreateItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(UserDataManagement.CATALOG, 0);
        String items = sp.getString("items", "");
        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(items);
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                JSONObject item = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = item.getString("id");
                String firstName = item.getString("first_name");
                String lastName = item.getString("last_name");
                String imageUrl = item.getString("image");
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageUrl).openStream();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                in.close();
                Item item = new Item(id, firstName, lastName, imageUrl, imageBitmap);
                itemList.add(item);
               /* if(i!=0 && i%10==0){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }*/
           }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
       return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create async tasks in a loop that will fetch images from the web in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that still did not work. The final solution that worked was to create a new Thread instead of async task and make it start immediately using concurrent latch countdown. I think my previous async task wasn't able to start immediately after the call or would have been getting blocked by something else.For fetching images over web, I used AsyncHttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution that worked was to create a new Thread instead of async task and make it start immediately using countdown latch. I think my previous async task wasn't able to start immediately after the call or would have been getting blocked by something else.For fetching images over web, I used AsyncHttpClient.

```
final java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Thread getInfo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            latch.countDown();
                            do something
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                   list.add(item);
                                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });
                  }
    });

            getInfo.start();
    try {
        latch.await();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```